# Width of image in html is not being changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have below code where I am trying to change the height and width of an image. For that, I gave height and width parameters in `<img >` tag.

Height of an image is being changed where as there is no affect on width. I want my image to be larger.

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; width: 1000px; height:100px">
        <img class="calIcons" src="@calLegend" alt="Legend" height="1000" width="100"/>
</div>
```

Image:

Dimensions 443x30
Width      443 pixels
Height     30 pixels
Bit depth  32

Comment: create a jsfiddle example

Comment: you don't work on css?

Comment: Yes I do. I have tried almost everything here using CSS also but didn't worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the class `calIcons` does not manipulate the width or size.

Make `width` and `height` of image tag `100%` and then adjust the width and height of the container div to whichever values you want. This works if the image is the only element in the div.

Comment: add the style for image - img {width:100%;}

Comment: When I tried below it gives me an error at width and height properties in img  tag.                                                                                                                                        <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; width: 1000px; height:100px">                                                                                                    
   <img class="calIcons" src="@calLegend" alt="Legend" width: 100% height:100% />                                                       
  </div>

Comment: Since you are passing width and height as attributes, you should do width=100% instead of width:100%

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `height` and `width` attributes, to keep it clean you can try something like the following within your **CSS** file:

```
div > img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Considering you have already set your dimension values within the parent `div`, you can just set the width and height to `100%` for the child `img`.

Alternatively, if you don't want the image to stretch;

You can set it as the `background-image` of a `div` with a `background-size` of `cover`.

Like so (**HTML**):

```
<div class="parent-div"> <!-- the parent div with the set dimensions !-->
    <div class="child-img"></div> <!-- the image !-->
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.parent-div{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.child-img{
    width: 100%; /* set the dimensions to 1000px x 100px */
    height: 100%;
    background: no-repeat url('image/location.jpg');
    background-size: cover; /* cover the whole div */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this. It will give you maximum dimensions of your image.

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; width: 1000px; height:100px">
        <img class="calIcons" src="@calLegend" alt="Legend" style= "width: 100%; height:100%"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I used below code but It give me an syntax error on width and height properties:                                                                                               <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; width: 1000px; height:100px">
        <img class="calIcons" src="@calLegend" alt="Legend" width: 100% height:100%/>
 </div>

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have updated my code. Try it now.